# bubble event down from base class to child

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a base class that several other classes extend from.  I want to add a common dialog function, with two button, in the base class.  Then, I want to have all classes that extend from this base class to be able to call this function, to show the dialog.  I got this part working.  Now, I want to bubble the event, of either button being pushed, from the base class to the child class.  This way, any child class can call it (passing in a different string to display a different message) and handle the click events differently.  Anyone have any advice on how to do this?  This is what I have so far:

**Base Class:**

```
var BaseClassView= Backbone.View.extend({
    //all my stuff
},{
//create dialog
showMsgDialog: function(message, id){
        if ($(window).data('blockUI.isBlocked')) {
            return;
        }
        this.deleteReportId = id;
        var yesButton = document.createElement('button');
        var y=document.createTextNode("Yes");
        yesButton.id = "dialogYes";
        yesButton.onclick=this.dialogResponseYes;
        yesButton.appendChild(y);


        var noButton = document.createElement('button');
        var n = document.createTextNode("No");
        noButton.id = "dialogNo";
        noButton.appendChild(n);

        var div1 = document.createElement("div");
        div1.style.color = "black";
        div1.style.width = "100%";
        div1.style.height = "66%";
        div1.innerHTML = message;
        div1.style.font.size = "15pt"

        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = "questionDlg";
        div.style.width = "100px";
        div.style.height = "100px";
        div.style.background = "white";
        div.style.color = "white";
        div.style.cursor = "default";
        div.style.display = "inline";
        div.appendChild(div1);
        div.appendChild(yesButton);
        div.appendChild(noButton);

        $.blockUI({
            message: div,
            css: {
                width: '200px',
                height: '100px',
                border: '1px solid blue',
                padding: '15px',
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
                '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
                opacity: 1,
                color: '#fff',
                fontSize: '26px',
                fontFamily: "'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica"
            }
        });
    },
    dialogResponseYes:function(e){
        var test = e;
        //throw event and parameter to child class

    },
    dialogResponseNo:function(e){
        var test = e;
        //throw event and parameter to child class
    },

});
```

**Child Class:**

```
var MyListView = BaseClassView.extend({
    events: {
        //my events   

    },
    initialize: function(options){

    },
    render: function() {
       //do stuff
    },
deleteReportClick:function(e){
    try {
       //stuff here, this works.  Removed for brevity
       ActivityDBView.showMsgDialog('Delete Report?', getReportId);          

    } catch (err) {
        window.app.displayError("Error Deleting Report.");
    }
},

dialogResponseYes: function(e){
   //catch event here
},
dialogResponseNo: function(e){
   //catch event here
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Version**

In your specific case your problem is that you aren't calling your show message dialog correctly, what you want to do is call it from your child class so that it goes up the prototype chain (or call it directly on it's parent).

So instead of

```
ActivityDBView.showMsgDialog('Delete Report?', getReportId);
```

Use

```
this.showMsgDialog('Delete Report?', getReportId);
```

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oFINOkIX/1/)

**Longer Version**

In general what you want to do is declare the events in your base class and then either provide a default handler there, or override it in your child class.

If you are using the backbone events hash then what you can do is declare your events hash as normal in your base class and then in your child class you can extend the events hash using it's prototype if you want to add events unique to the child class. Within any of the methods of your child class you can call it's base class's *version* of the method also using it's prototype.

For example to extend the events hash

```
 var MyListView = BaseClassView.extend({

  events: _.extend({
      //events that are just in the child class
    }, BaseClassView.prototype.events),
```

Similarly if you want to call a base class method within a child class method you can call it using it's prototype

```
dialogResponseYes: function(e){
   BaseClassView.prototype.dialogResponseYes.call(this);
   //catch event here
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am still rather new to backbone, so I'm not sure I follow.  In the base class ShowMsgDialog function, I declare my event like this: yesButton.onclick=this.dialogResponseYes;  Should I move that to the events section of the base class?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that I want the base class event to fire but handle the event in the child class, as each child class may use the yes/no button events differently.

Comment: Are the buttons part of the same part of the DOM(that is are the descendents of it's `el`) as the base class? If yes then when you declare the events in your base class's event's hash they are delegated to the root `el`, if you provide a handler in you child class that will be called instead.

Comment: If not you can still achieve the same sort of effect if a bit less elegantly. What you can then do is something along the lines of having your handlers in your base class trigger an event on the the base class view's `el` and subscribe to that in your child classes.

Comment: First try declaring the handler in your child class. That should get called when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your patience.  I did declare it like this:  dialogResponseYes: function(e){
   //catch event here
},  in the child class.  It does not work.  If i put it into the parent, it gets hit, but I dont know how to pass it on the the child after that.

Comment: I think your problem is in how your calling the method to create the dialog, for example `BaseClassView.protoype.showMsgDialog.call(this, 'Delete Report?', getReportId);`